# NULL values with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 forms in php for adding the supplier and customer. On these forms I can add contact of supplier or customer. Now, I made foreign key on table contact since 1 supplier or 1 customer can have many contacts. But the problem is that I have 1 contact table, structured like this:

```
ID  |  telefon  |  name  |  mail  |  type_fk  | supplier_fk_id  |  customer_id_fk
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  123      | john   | mail   |     1     |       23        |      NULL
2   |  123234   | julie  | gfdh   |     3     |       NULL      |      45
```

So basically, I want that to be stored in one table, and right now I'm not sure if that was a good idea. Since when I add customer contacts I have NULL value in supplier_fk_id, and same this for the supplier but in customer_fk_id. I have foreign keys on update and on delete - cascade since I want those contacts to be deleted if the customer/supplier is deleted. If I remove the foreign keys in the database I won't have the database side check which I want. But I get error like this:

```
Error   
Error inserting:
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`testbase`.`pro_contact`, CONSTRAINT `supplier_fk_id` FOREIGN KEY (`supplier_fk_id`) 
REFERENCES `pro_supplier` (`supplier_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Any advice would be appreciated...

Comment: you want to delete records from which table(s)?

Comment: in the contact table, if the supplier or customer is deleted I want his contacts to be deleted

Comment: IIUC, you want a table for all the people(supplier and consumer) and one table for contacts(which supplier knows which consumer and vice versa) with CASCADE ON DELETE. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: nope. :) I have 1 table for customer, 1 for supplier and 1 for their contacts. If I add supplier than I add his contacts and that data is stored in contacts table with FK/PK from supplier, vice versa for customer.

Answer (score 0):

I think use `ON DELETE SET NULL` for `SUPPLIER/CONTACTS` and
 `ON DELETE CASCADE` for `CUSTOMER/CONTACTS` or vice/versa based on your decision

Comment: i think that is not working since I can't insert the NULL value, you misundrestood it

Comment: system automatically replace `supplier_fk_id` from `contacts`to `NULL` , when correspondent record from `supplier` deleted.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. I know how on delete and on update work, I want to put the NULL value in the foreign key field with foreign keys created for that field.